# json object inside php object encode

Tags: php, mysql, json

Currently getting json results:

```
  {

    "post_company_success_company_address_ibfk_1": [
        "123 Main Street N\/A Cincinnati Ohio 45500"
    ]
}
```

The goal is include address as a separate JSON object in an array attribute of the company object.

I have tried this:

```
  $real= json_encode(['post_company_success_'.$randomname => {[  $result2]}], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

It did not work.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Comment: You can only parse one JSON document at a time with `JSON.parse`. If you have multiple documents, split them apart and process them individually.

Comment: how tadman like $result1=$data; $result2=$data2; $combo = $result1.$result2; echo json_encode($combo, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. How do those relate to `$combo`?

Comment: because combo would be result1 = result2 ...is that not how to do it?

Comment: You could `json_encode([ $result1, $result2 ])` for example, that "combines" them into an array.

Comment: that fixed it but output looks like "\"New record created successfully\""
1 "\"New record created suc… into company address\""

Comment: That's what you're asking for given the values of `$data` involved here. What were you intending instead?

Comment: I was thinking maybe that standard output with {} and without the "\"

Comment: The `\"` part is because you're embedding strings within a JSON string, so that's normal if you're looking at it in `var_dump` mode. When you actually send it the escaping disappears, it's just there for presentation purposes. `\"` means *literal quote*, nothing more.

Comment: If you want it structured as a JSON object you'll need to do `json_encode([ 'data1' => $data1, 'data2' => $data2 ])` where that's an associative-array in PHP and a JSON object in JSON. If you have strings the `\"` stuff will still be there, of course. That's only not present for numbers and such.

Comment: did what you said: {
    "result1": "\"New record created successfully\"",
    "result2": "\"New record created successfully into company address\""
} ...there has to be a way to remove the "\"

Comment: see update please tadman

Comment: Don't double `json_encode`. Do it once and once only with the right structure.

Comment: please see question update

Comment: Did that work? It looks plausible, though the `{ [ ... ] }` part is a bit questionable.

Comment: all good now used array ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick with JSON encoding is to structure your data into a singular object of some kind, typically some kind of array, and then call `json_encode` on it once.

For example:

```
json_encode([ 'key1' => $data1, 'key2' => $data2 ]);
```

If you concatenate multiple JSON documents together that's not valid from a JSON perspective, so any assembly you perform will need to be undone on the receiving end before processing and parsing.

There are quasi-standards like [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org) or [Line-Delimited JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming#Line-delimited_JSON) which specify how to encode multiple documents, but these are outside of the JSON specification itself.